# Passing map with custom comparator to function

Tags: c++, function, c++11, dictionary

I have an STL map with a custom comparator which I want to pass to a function, but the function doesn't recognize the custom comparator.

Trying to access the map within the main function works.

I have listed both attempts in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

// Error: cmpByStringLength is not recognized (both times)
void funcOut(std::map<std::string, int, cmpByStringLength> myMap)
{
  for (std::map<std::string, int, cmpByStringLength>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  // Reverse sort by length
  struct cmpByStringLength {
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
      return a.length() > b.length();
    }
  };

  std::map<std::string, int, cmpByStringLength> myMap;
  myMap.emplace("String 1", 5);
  myMap.emplace("String 123", 10);

  funcOut(myMap);

  // Working
  for (std::map<std::string, int, cmpByStringLength>::iterator it = myMap.begin(); it != myMap.end(); ++it)
  {
    std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to put `cmpByStringLength` definition on top of funcOut function

Comment: Move the struct at the top of the file above the function. Like anything else you need at least a declaration (and in this case a definition) for things to be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use a name after its declaration, and only if it's in scope. Your comparator type is scoped within `main`, so you can only use it in that function. Move the definition out of `main`, into the global namespace (or in another namespace if you like), to make it available in other functions.

Alternatively, you could make the other function a template, so it can work with any map type:

```
template <typename Map>
void funcOut(Map const & myMap) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Ah I tried that, but that gave me some kind of overload error, but moving it to the very top, above the function worked!

Comment: @CGuy: Yes, you have to declare it before use, as I said.

Comment: Where would I ideally place the map declaration and custom comparator if I have to use it between multiple files and methods of classes?

Make a separate class?

Comment: @CGuy: If they're needed in multiple files, then you'd define the class and, if you really want a global variable, declare it `extern` in a header. Include that from each file that needs it, and define the variable (without `extern`) in a source file.

Answer (score 3):

Use a template, because I'm a lazy c++ developer (I don't need to worry about lots of details...) I would do..

```
template <typename MapType>
void funcOut(MapType& myMap)
{
  for (auto& p : myMap)
  {
    std::cout << p.first << " => " << p.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```